# How can I check whether a variable is empty before assigning it in PHP smarty?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

First off I'm not a PHP developer. I'm primarily from a .net stack background. I'm helping a friend with an e-commerce site and in one of his modules I came across the following code:

```
$this->smarty->assign(array(
        'first_name' => $params['cookie']->customer_firstname,
        'last_name' => $params['cookie']->customer_lastname,
        'email' => $params['cookie']->email,
        'contact_number' => $address->phone,
        'address_line_one' => $address->address1,
        'address_line_two' => $address->address2,
        'city' => $address->city,
        'postal_code' => $address->postcode,
        'Country' => $address->country
    ));
```

What I would like to do here is to check whether **$address->phone** is empty and if so, assign **$address->phone_mobile** instead. If it's not, then the existing assignment should take place. Could someone help me achieve this please?

**P.S.-** In case it matters, Prestashop is used as the e-commerce solution.

Comment: whay not:
if (isset($address->phone)) {
$this->smarty->assign(array(
        'first_name' => $params['cookie']->customer_firstname,
        'last_name' => $params['cookie']->customer_lastname,
        'email' => $params['cookie']->email,
        'contact_number' => $address->phone_mobile,
        'address_line_one' => $address->address1,
        'address_line_two' => $address->address2,
        'city' => $address->city,
        'postal_code' => $address->postcode,
        'Country' => $address->country
    ));
}else{...}

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht Unfortunately there's quite a bit of code duplication in this approach. Thanks for taking the time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the empty variation of the ternary operator:

```
'contact_number' => $address->phone ?: $address->phone_mobile,
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wane know if the var exist you can use isset()

```
'contact_number' => isset($address->phone) ? $address->phone : $address->phone_mobile;
```

if you are sure than the var exist but you wane know if is an empty text

```
'contact_number' => strlen($address->phone) > 0 ? $address->phone : $address->phone_mobile;
```

Comment: Thanks for going the extra step to show how to check whether the var exists as well!